# Неправильный тип данных в функции in_array в Kohana?

Tags: php, kohana

У меня из модели возвращаются данные в базовый контроллер и присваиваются парочку переменным таким образом:

```
class Controller_Base extends Controller_Template {

public $template = 'main';

public function before()
{
    parent::before();

    $webs = array();
    $apps = array();

    $app = new Model_Application();
    $apps = $app->get_all();

    $web = new Model_Web();
    $webs = $web->get_all();

    $this->template->content = '';
    $this->template->styles = array('style');
    $this->template->scripts = '';

    $this->template->webs = $webs;
    $this->template->apps = $apps;

}

}
```

в виде они уже идут как массив, а вот в контроллере я пока не пойму как задействовать функцию **in_array**, если сделаю так (контроллер subject, метод all):

```
 class Controller_Subject extends Controller_Base {

public function action_all()
{

    $url = $this->request->param('url');

    $this->template->caption = $url;

    if (in_array($url,$this->template->webs)) { 
        echo "web";
    }
        elseif (in_array($url,$this->template->apps)) { 
        echo "apps";
    }

    $links = array("a"=>"1","b"=>"2");

    $view = View::factory('subject')
                ->set('links',$links);

    $this->template->content = $view;

}

}
```

то `Kohana` выдаст ошибку:

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: in_array() [<a href='function.in-array'>function.in-array</a>]: Wrong datatype for second argument
```

Как же все-таки проверить прямо в контроллере есть ли допустим значение "`test`" в массиве `webs`?

**Решение**

```
$webs = web->get_all()->as_array();
$apps = app->get_all()->as_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (in_array("test",  $webs)) { 
        echo "web"; 
    }
        elseif (in_array("test", $apps)) { 
        echo "apps";
    }
```

Comment: хотя я наверно не правильно Вас понял. Вы в этом же методе before() хотите выполнить действия с in_array или в другом?

Comment: не не не, это уже совсем другой контроллер, ща обновлю.

Comment: Возможно стоит занести эти значения в сессию $this->session->set('webs', $webs) и затем проверять в другом контроллере $webs = $this->session->get('webs'); и потом то, что я написал в ответе

Comment: нет, сессии тут ну ни к селу ни к месту если честно.

Comment: одно ясно, $webs как объект получается, как его в массив переделать хмм.. если var_dump($this->template->webs) сделать то вот такой резалт: ``object(Database_MySQL_Result)#24 (7) { ["_internal_row:protected"]=> int(0) ["_query:protected"]=> string(18) "SELECT * FROM webs" ["_result:protected"]=> resource(73) of type (mysql result) ["_total_rows:protected"]=> int(5) ["_current_row:protected"]=> int(0) ["_as_object:protected"]=> bool(false) ["_object_params:protected"]=> NULL }``